# How do I get KeycloakSecurityContext to be set in the httpServletRequest in Keycloak's account-linking doc?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

In Keycloak's [account-linking](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/server_development/topics/identity-brokering/account-linking.html) documentation, there's a code snippet:
`KeycloakSecurityContext session = (KeycloakSecurityContext) httpServletRequest.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName())`

Why would the `KeycloakSecurityContext` be set in the `httpServletRequest`? Where does this code should run? In what context? Thanks.

Comment: Mailing list: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-October/011941.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documentation this code can reside in a Java servlet. The server side application containing this servlet must be protected by a Keycloak OIDC adapter to get the logged-in user's security context in the request.
The user must be logged in already to invoke the account-linking. That's a prerequisite listed in the documentation:
   `The application must already be logged in as an existing user via the OIDC protocol`